# Angularjs dynamic table from multiple dropdown selects

Tags: angularjs

I have two select inputs, which options i get from the controller. When both of these inputs are selected, there needs to be a table with certain data. In this case, you need to select bus number and a bus stop, then a table appears with hours and minutes for each hour. I'm fresh to Angular so I don't really know how to tackle this.
So far I have this: https://plnkr.co/edit/U7FmkwNLbxb0bmMbV561?p=preview

The markup:

```
    <div ng-app="timeTable" ng-controller="ngCtrl">
    <section class="content">
        <section class="filter-wrapper">
            <h2>Bus No.:
            <span><select ng-model="selectedNo" ng-options="x for x in busNum"></select></span>
            </h2>
            <h4>Stop name: <span><select ng-model="selectedStop" ng-options="x for x in stopName"></select></span>
            </h4>
        </section>
        <table class="time-table">
            <tr ng-repeat="time in time">
                <th>{{time.hour}}</th>
                <td ng-repeat="minute in time.minutes">{{minute}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </section>
    <footer class="footer">

    </footer>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var app = angular.module("timeTable", []);   
    app.controller("ngCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.busNum = [1, 2, 3];
    $scope.stopName = ["Stop1", "Stop2", "Stop3"];
    $scope.time = [
        {
            hour: 7,
            minutes: [num, num, num, num]
        },
        {
            hour: 8,
            minutes: [num, num, num, num]
        }
        //And so on...
    ];
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to make changes to your data model. 
I've made [this simple plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rMcuX0Otl4LqhYSwVpPH?p=preview) for you.

You can see that I've added more complex model for your bus timetable. This way you will be able to actually display times that refer to that particular bus number and bus stop. Keep in mind, that in my current example only BusNr1 and BusStop1 work, but you should be able to get the idea and continue inserting your times.

You might also need in the end to change the

```
$scope.busNum = [1, 2, 3];
$scope.stopName = ["stop1", "stop2", "stop3"];
```

to objects with key and value pairs.

Comment: Yes! That's what I was looking for. Thank you for your help. Maybe I need a json for the bus and stops data?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what you need, especially when returning data form the server.

Comment: So how should I do it, so it will be displayed correctly?